# продолжительность авторизации в Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Где и как можно установить какое время пользователь будет авторизован на сайте? Сейчас у меня приложение работает так, что, если авторизоваться, закрыть браузер и снова зайти на сайт авторизация спадает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря [этой статье](http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-remember-me-example-with-hibernate/) разобрался как реализовать сохранение сессии на необходимое время.

Сначала нужно создать дополнительную таблицу в БД для хранения информации о сессиях.

```
CREATE TABLE persistent_logins (
    username VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    series VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    token VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    last_used TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (series)
);
```

Далее в конфигурацию Spring'a нужно добавить следущее:

```
<remember-me
        remember-me-parameter="remember-me"
        remember-me-cookie="remember-me"
        token-validity-seconds="86400"
    data-source-ref="dataSource" />
```

В JSP добавляется чек бокс с атрибутом `name` значение которого равно тому, что указано в `remember-me-parameter`:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="rememberme" name="remember-me">
```

После этих манипуляций по окончании авторизации в браузере должна появится `cookie` с именем указанным в `remember-me-cookie`.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/118053)

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас так и сделаю.